# Programmatically Open PDFs in Adobe Document Cloud

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

We currently have O365 Adobe Cloud integration, and this works on our standard libraries in SharePoint Online. However, we make use of provider hosted add-ins with our own custom functionality, and the pdf links in these forms point to the Sharepint PDF viewer, at which point the user needs to click "Open in Adobe Document Cloud" in order to edit the PDFs.

Is there a way to modify these pdf links so they point directly to Adobe Document Cloud?

an example link in would look like this:

`https://{sharepointTenant}/Workpapers/Forms/Summary.aspx?id=%2Fsites{siteUrl}Workpapers%TestPdfFile%2Epdf&parent={siteUrl}Workpapers`

Which then allows me to click "open in adobe document cloud" button here, but we would like to go directly to the document cloud from our generated url above:
[image: adobe image]

Note that these are custom generated links, we've already enabled the default behavior, etc. I know the file will open directly to adobe document cloud through SPO OOTB functionality, as clicking a file link in a library like below will execute the same functionality we are trying to code for:

[image: PDF Link]

Answer (score 0):

After contacting Adobe support, this is the response I received:

"I understand what you are looking for and I checked it with engineering as well.
Unfortunately, Adobe doesn't have  such feature in Acrobat for SharePoint/OneDrive yet."

So, it can't be one at this point